# Create topic in phpBB3 by php file

Tags: php, phpbb, phpbb3

I am trying to create topics in phpBB3 forums by a php file.

I found this

[Creating a forum in phpBB3 from PHP and settings permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258296/creating-a-forum-in-phpbb3-from-php-and-settings-permissions)

But when i copy this and running my php file i am getting this

```
  PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant FORUMS_TABLE - assumed 'FORUMS_TABLE' in /var/www/html/phpvibe/forum/insertPhpbb.php on line 13
  PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function sql_build_array() on a non-object in /var/www/html/phpvibe/forum/insertPhpbb.php on line 14
```

I also found this

https://wiki.phpbb.com/Using_phpBB3%27s_Basic_Functions

After that i wrote this code:-

```
<?php
require_once("/var/www/html/phpvibe/forum/includes/functions.php");
require_once("/var/www/html/phpvibe/forum/includes/functions_posting.php"    );
// note that multibyte support is enabled here 
$my_subject = "test";
$my_text    = "testdata";
// variables to hold the parameters for submit_post
$poll = $uid = $bitfield = $options = ''; 
generate_text_for_storage($my_subject, $uid, $bitfield, $options, false, false, false);
generate_text_for_storage($my_text, $uid, $bitfield, $options, true, true, true);

$data = array( 
    'forum_id'      => 2,
    'icon_id'       => false,

    'enable_bbcode'     => true,
    'enable_smilies'    => true,
    'enable_urls'       => true,
    'enable_sig'        => true,

    'message'       => $my_text,
    'message_md5'   => md5($my_text),

    'bbcode_bitfield'   => $bitfield,
    'bbcode_uid'        => $uid,

    'post_edit_locked'  => 0,
    'topic_title'       => $my_subject,
    'notify_set'        => false,
    'notify'            => false,
    'post_time'         => 0,
    'forum_name'        => '',
    'enable_indexing'   => true,
);

print_r(submit_post('post', $my_subject, '', POST_NORMAL, $poll, $data));
?>
```

But no topics is created in forum. I also checked 'phpbb_topics' and phpbb_posts table my data is not inserted there.

Comment: What's your problem whit your code?

Comment: I dont know, But topics is not created in phpbb3 forum.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

We need to add these piece of code at the top of the script and need to remove our extra 'require_once'.

```
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = './';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.') , 1);
error_reporting(0);
include ($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);

include ($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_posting.' . $phpEx);

$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup();
```