# Create post in phpBB by script

Tags: php, phpbb, phpbb3

This question is related to this post

[Create topic in phpBB3 by php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626221/create-topic-in-phpbb3-by-php-file)

Now i am able to create topics in phpBB form by script. Now my problem is, I want to post/replies in newly created topics.

For this i modified submit function like this:-

```
         $data = array(
            'forum_id' => 8,
            'icon_id' => false,
            'enable_bbcode' => true,
            'enable_smilies' => true,
            'enable_urls' => true,
            'enable_sig' => true,
            'post_visibility' => 1,

            'topic_id' =>$topicId,  //this is newly created topic id. 
            'poster_id' => 2,
            'post_text' => "Myreply",
            'notify_set' => false,
            'notify' => false,
            'post_visibility' => 1,
            'post_edit_locked' => 0,
            'post_time' => 0,
            'enable_indexing' => true,
            'force_approved_state' => true,
        );
        submit_post('post', $my_subject, '', POST_NORMAL, $poll, $data);
```

But replies are not created. If i use old question variables then topics is created not replies.

So how i can create replies by this function?

**UPDATE**

I notice that i am getting this while i am passing data in 'post_text'

```
  Column 'post_text' cannot be null [1048]<br /><br />An SQL error occurred while fetching this page.
```

Comment: If i directly insert data in phpbb_post table then every-time i need to synchronize forum, from admin area so this is not a good idea to insert replies.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the docs of [submit_post()](https://wiki.phpbb.com/Function.submit_post), the body of the message (the post text), should be in the `message` field of the array you're passing to the function not in a `post_text` field.

Comment: Thanks but now i am getting 'Column 'forum_id' cannot be null [1048]', While i am giving forum_id.

Answer (score 0):

The mode (first parameter of `submit_post()`) should be `reply` for replies, and `post` for new topics.